# JAXB take all content of element (both tags and text)

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have an XML of a forml like this: `<content><p>Text</p><p>Text</p></content>`
How can I map with JAXB annotations all the content to a String value.

```
public class Content {
    String value;
}
```

So `Content.value = "<p>Text</p><p>Text</p>"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `@XmlAnyElement` annotation and specify a DOMHandler to convert the DOM fragment to/from a String value.

For a Complete Example

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/xmlanyelement-and-non-dom-properties.html

Comment: Works great, I've been trying to do this all morning, thanks a lot :)