# JaxB annotation driven extracting

Tags: jaxb

First of all I am new to Jaxb and  most defiantly have not wrapped my head completely around it.

I would like to use annotation to pares Xml but instead of generating binding classes
I would just like to extract a portion of the xml and return it as a Java.lang.String.
No marshalling or unmarshalling need. Just want to extract from xml.

Let's say my XML is structured as followed

```
 <root>
   <topMovies>
     <string>The Godfather (1972)</string>
     <string>The Shawshank Redemption (1994)</string>
     <string>The Godfather: Part II (1974)</string>
     <string>The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King (2003)</string>
  <topMovies>
 <root>
```

And I would like to extract the above XML snippet (topMovies).

This won't work of course but might give an idea of what I am trying to say.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
public class GetTopMovies {
@XmlElement(name = "topMovies")
    protected java.lang.String getTopMovies;
}
```

In the end I want a java String with the extracted xml (not taking 
escaping into account).

```
String topMovies =
 "<topMovies>
   <string>The Godfather (1972)</string>
   <string>The Shawshank Redemption (1994)</string>
   <string>The Godfather: Part II (1974)</string>
   <string>The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King (2003)</string>
   <topMovies>
 ";
```

Can this be done with JAXBElement or and XmlAdapter or creating a special Object Factory?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JAXB take all content of element (both tags and text)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7736678/jaxb-take-all-content-of-element-both-tags-and-text)

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the `@XmlAnyElement` annotation with a `DOMHandler` to accomplish this use case:

Below are links to answers I gave, to similar questions that contain additional details:

- [JAXB take all content of element (both tags and text)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7736678/jaxb-take-all-content-of-element-both-tags-and-text/7738435#7738435)
- [Using JAXB to extract inner text of XML element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537416/using-jaxb-to-extract-inner-text-of-xml-element/5553682#5553682)

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/xmlanyelement-and-non-dom-properties.html

Comment: Thank you. I see I need to improve my Google skills :)